# Push log file into SAP BODS with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, sap-data-services

I need to look for a string of text in a log file.

When that string of text is found, I want to get the next 4 lines of text immediately after, see my example below:

```
Example found text string
first line after found string 
second line after found string 
third line after found string 
forth line after found string
```

My code is :

```
'strFileName = "D:\write123.xls" 
'Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
'objExcel.Visible = True 
'Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add() 
'objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName) 
'objExcel.Quit 
Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("D:\mic.txt",1) 
strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadAll() 
objFileToRead.Close 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFileToWrite = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\write123.xlsx", 2) 
objFileToWrite.Write strFileText 
objFileToWrite.Close
```

Any help or any alternative or any **Script** given would be greatly appreciated, I just want to fetch the content of the log file into my target table.

Thanks
chirag

Comment: Hi, What have you tried already? [so] isn't a code writing service, but we'll be happy to help you with problems in code you've already written.  Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hi  my code is :  'strFileName = "D:\write123.xls"
'Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'objExcel.Visible = True
'Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
'objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName)
'objExcel.Quit



Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("D:\mic.txt",1)
strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
objFileToRead.Close



Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFileToWrite = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\write123.xlsx", 2)
objFileToWrite.Write strFileText
objFileToWrite.Close

Comment: it says "file not found ", i tried putting the files in every path . but still not  getting.  Could you please help so that i can write the content of log files into excel file.

Comment: If you want to write the output into an Excel file, it's significantly better to use the `Excel.Application` object and to reference it that way.  You're probably getting `file not found` because `D:\write123.xlsx` doesn't exist, you don't create it, and you probably don't want to write a text file with an .xlsx. file type anyway since Excel will just call it corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim objFileToRead : Set objFileToRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\mic.txt",1) 
dim myArray(0)
While Not objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFileToRead.ReadLine
    myArray(UBound(myArray)) = strLine
    reDim Preserve myArray(UBound(myArray)+1)
Wend
objFileToRead.Close 
Dim objExcelApp : Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
dim myExcel : Set myExcel = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
With myExcel.Worksheets(1)
    For myLoop = 0 to UBound(myArray)
        .Range("A" & myLoop).Value = myArray(myLoop)
    Next
End With
myExcel.SaveAs Filename:="D:\write123.xlsx"
myExcel.Close
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objFileToRead = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

What this code does is reads the entire content of the logfile into an array; create an instance of Excel and a workbook; for each row in the array of log entries, enter it into the "A" column; save and close the workbook before quitting Excel.  Let me know if you need any more explanation of what's happening here?